# Cannot import OpenSSL in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am seeing this error all around but all the fixes seem to address older versions. I am trying to import OpenSSL in jupyter notebook with python3 kernel and get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7404f32edce4> in <module>()
----> 1 import OpenSSL
      2 print(pyOpenSSL.__version__)

~/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 """
      7 
----> 8 from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
      9 from OpenSSL.version import __version__
     10 

~/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in <module>()
    116 SSL_ST_ACCEPT = _lib.SSL_ST_ACCEPT
    117 SSL_ST_MASK = _lib.SSL_ST_MASK
--> 118 SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
    119 SSL_ST_BEFORE = _lib.SSL_ST_BEFORE
    120 SSL_ST_OK = _lib.SSL_ST_OK

AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

After checking the version:

```
!pip3 show pyopenssl
Name: pyOpenSSL
Version: 17.5.0
Summary: Python wrapper module around the OpenSSL library
Home-page: https://pyopenssl.org/
Author: Hynek Schlawack
Author-email: hs@ox.cx
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, cryptography
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Possibly related?](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/issues/293)

Comment: Tried with 16.2.0 as well, no change!